# Error parsing Date with RFC_1123_DATE_TIME (Java)

Tags: java, date, datetimeformatter

I am extracting a Date object from a String using this piece of code:

```
Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(exchange.getIn().getHeader("Date").toString(), DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).toInstant());
```

But I have errors when the String is something like that: `Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)`

How can I parse this kind of string obtaining a Date object? Do I need to use another DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: Are you sure you need an old-fashioned `Date`? If you are not, I recommend you stick to `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime`).

Comment: If I remember correctly from reading the RFC, there are numerous variants that `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` does not cover.

Comment: If I understand RFC 1123 and RFC 822 correctly, everything in parentheses is a *comment* meant for humans and should be ignored by the computer. In your case the `(CET)`. If the comment always comes at the end, you can parse as much of the string as you can and ignore the rest: `OffsetDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse("Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)", new ParsePosition(0)))`. This yields `2019-11-26T09:00:01+01:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the string in the format "Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)". The format you provided contains additional information in parentheses, which is not part of the standard RFC 1123 format.

Here's an example of how you might have some code to handle that case using a custom `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

String dateString = "Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzz)");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

This defined a custom `DateTimeFormatter` matching the format "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzz)".

- EEE: day of the week
- d: day of the month
- MMM: abbreviated month name
- yyyy: year
- HH: hours
- mm: minutes
- ss: seconds
- Z: time zone offset
- zzz: time zone abbreviation

Following that, parse `dateString` using the formatter, returning a `ZonedDateTime` object. Grab the `Instant` from `ZonedDateTime` and convert it back to `Date`. This should successfully parse the string you provided and do so via a `Date` object.

Sample Java Class

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DateTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzz)");
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
        Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
        Date date = Date.from(instant);

        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Given the string: "Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)"
This program prints: Tue Nov 26 03:00:01 EST 2019.

Perhaps I did not need to specify parsing because my installation is already set to an English speaking locale, but you can try the Locale.ROOT parameter at the end of the parser.

Comment: I tried, but the code you posted gives me `Text 'Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:00:01 +0100 (CET)' could not be parsed at index 0`

Comment: For validation i would additionally parse separately into an `OffsetDateTime`, which will use the offset, and a `ZonedDateTime`, wihch will use the time zone abbreviation, and check if the offsets of the two parsed date-times match.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 1123 section 5.2.14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55) and [RFC 822 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5), the `(CET)` shouldn't be there. The zone should be either the zone (`CET`) or the offset (`+0100`) but not both. However, [RFC_1123_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) mentions this:

> This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing most of the RFC-1123 format. RFC-1123 updates RFC-822 changing the year from two digits to four. This implementation requires a four digit year. This implementation also does not handle North American or military zone names, only 'GMT' and offset amounts.

In other words, unless the time zone is `GMT`, only offsets are supported.

If you still need to support dates like the example you gave you'll need to create your own `DateTimeFormatter` instance. When using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` you can include [optional parts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOptional(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)).

Edit: here's a formatter you can use:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(" (z)"))
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT)
```